# Click on "This comment adds something useful to the post"

Tags: support, comment, voting

I like to see that a comment I wrote is marked by somebody as useful. In the overall of my make comments it serves as a feedback (and it's nice to read something equivalent to "good point"). But apart of this, what consequences has it, in reputation or something? I've searched in this part of the site, math. and math.meta, and I didn't find anything more than the obvious, that you can click to increase that index.

Comment: Similar to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17197/should-upvoted-comments-gain-reputation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Voting on comments has **no effect** on reputation.

Once there are too much comments, the ones with lower scores will be hidden by default (you have to click 'Show more comments...' then), so upvoting the comment will increase its visibility.

Also, comments with five upvotes count towards the [Pundit](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/56/pundit) badge.

Comment: Ah, yes. I didn't get why some of them were hidden. By the way, sometimes is very uncomfortable.